# TF Keras: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I have sequences of 2D Vectors that form patterns. I want to predict how the sequence continues.
I have a start_xy array constisting of arrays with the order, start_x and start_y:
e.g. [1, 2.4, 3.8]
and the same for the end_xy.

I want to train a model a sequence prediction model:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import training_data_generator
tdg = training_data_generator.training_data_generator(500)
trainingdata = tdg.produceTrainingSequences()
print("Printing DATA!:")
start_xy =[]
end_xy =[]

for batch in trainingdata:
    for pattern in batch:
        order = 1
        for sequence in pattern:
            start = [order,sequence[0],sequence[1]] 
            start_xy.append(start)
            end = [order,sequence[2],sequence[3]]
            end_xy.append(end)
            order = order +1

    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(2,len(start_xy))))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(start_xy,end_xy,batch_size=len(start_xy), epochs=5000,  verbose=2)
```

But I get the error message:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [320, 3]
```

I suspect I have to reshape my inputs somehow, but I don't yet understand how.
How do I make this work?
Am I even doing this the right way?

Comment: Could you post the complete code with the dataset on google colab or github for me to debug. I want to see what is the shape of the data you input and what is your end goal.

Comment: I've pushed my code to https://github.com/mylittlemachinelearning/sequenceprediction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mostly just have to convert your data into numpy arrays and do some reshaping of that data so that the model will accept it.

First convert start_xy into a numpy array and reshape it to have 3 dims:

```
start_xy = np.array(start_xy)
start_xy = start_xy.reshape(*start_xy.shape, 1)
```

Next fix the input shape for the LSTM layer to be [3, 1]:

```
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, input_shape=start_xy.shape[1:]))
```

Let me know if the error persists or if another one comes up!

Comment: That solved my original problem, so it's definitely the solution to this :-) on the other hand I get now "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'int\'>", "<class \'numpy.float64\'>"})'})" but that's a different question